# After server move several images not working

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, product-images

Since a recent move of server from staging to a live environment several images do not seem to work. i tried deleting entire image cache and such but no result.

See this product for example. just 1 image not working, while in the back-end it is visible. reuploading solves it, but i cannot ask to reupload 30% of all images.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this [link](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-images-not-showing/). Possible reason and solutions are mentioned here!

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that 80% of the images where bigger than 10MB each. (8000px width) here fore the pages gave me a 500 internal server error becuase GD library needed way to much memory. Via a ini_set or htacces i upgraded to 128M which was still to much. There where 2 solutions

- 1 Making the source images smaller so the GD library does not fail on generating the thumbnails
- 2 temporary make the memory_size limit 512M so it generates all smaller previews.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have made a mistake during the migration., if it worked originally and doesn't now.

Repeat the migration, use rsync to clone the document root to ensure its an identical replica.